# How can I run all the tests of a class sequentially using each dataset from @DataProvider in TestNG

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a test class with few tests in it.
A data provider which takes data from excel sheet.

What I am trying to achieve is having one data set, say dataset1, and run all the tests of the test class, say Test1, Test2, Test3...
Then go to dataset2 and using that data run Test1, Test2, Test3..

Any help to implemented this kind of data driven approach using TestNG would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To run all the tests of a class sequentially using each dataset from a `@DataProvider` in TestNG, you can utilize the `dependsOnMethods` attribute along with dynamic test names. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class MyTestClass {
  
  @Test(dataProvider = "myDataProvider")
  public void myTestMethod(String data) {
    System.out.println("Test execution with data: " + data);
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "myDataProvider")
  public Object[][] myDataProvider() {
    // Return your data sets here, for example, from an Excel sheet
    return new Object[][] {
      {"dataset1"},
      {"dataset2"},
      // Add more datasets as needed
    };
  }

  @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"myTestMethod"}, dataProvider = "myDataProvider")
  public void runTestsSequentially(String data) {
    // This method acts as a placeholder to run the tests sequentially for each dataset
    // No actual test code is required here
  }
}
```

In the above example, the `myTestMethod` is the actual test method that will be executed for each dataset. The `myDataProvider` is the data provider method that returns the datasets from an Excel sheet or any other source.

The `runTestsSequentially` method is added with the `dependsOnMethods` attribute, which specifies that it depends on the `myTestMethod`. This ensures that the tests run sequentially for each dataset.

By using this approach, all the tests in the class will be executed sequentially for each dataset returned by the data provider.